# Vaadin UI between sessions

Tags: user-interface, tomcat, vaadin, vaadin-flow

When I am creating a new session (or try to access from an other computer) in Vaadin Flow I get this error:

> Can't move a node from one state tree to another

From [this link](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17884943/can-t-move-a-node-from-one-state-tree-to-another), I read something about `UI` and `getUIId()`.

However, I don't understand how I should change my application in order to fix the error.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail about what you're trying to achieve by creating a new session? You should also share some code.

Comment: By new session I mean if I try to access it in a new tab or from an other computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Denis mentioned in the forum post you linked, wrong scope sounds like the most likely culprit. In other words, you are trying to use the exact same component instance in two different UIs, when both UIs should have their own instance. It's not possible to use the same instance in two places at the same time.

You can find the documentation for Vaadin Spring scopes here: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/flow/integrations/spring/scopes

Comment: As I can understand from your link it is about Route. In my application I have only one Route. The empty Route. Do I have to have more route ( which I don't like)or I can do something else?

Answer (score 1):

One possible cause of errors such as that is that if you're storing a Component in a `static` variable. You shouldn't do that - a Component instance can only belong to a single UI. A single UI in turn (in practice) means a single browser tab.